# Scrapy getting response url inside CrawlSpider rule

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this rule:

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('http://.*/category/.*/.*/.*',))),
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('http://.*/product/.*', )),cb_kwargs={'crumbs':response.url},callback='parse_item'),
```

I want to pass the first response to the function (parse_item), but the problem is that this line of code gives me an error response is not defined.

How do I access the response of last rule ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `Response` object only in the *callback*, try this:

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'http://.*/category/.*/.*/.*'), callback='parse_cat', follow=True),
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'http://.*/product/.*'), callback='parse_prod'),

def parse_cat(self, response):
    crumbs = response.url
    return self.parse_item(response, crumbs)

def parse_prod(self, response):
    crumbs = response.url
    return self.parse_item(response, crumbs)

def parse_item(self, response, crumbs):
    ...
```

Comment: I want the response of the first rule not the second one, this will get me the last response

Comment: You can have a callback for each `Rule` if you want: updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the category url (referer url) through which you came to the product, inside `parse_item`, you can access it by:

```
response.request.headers.get('Referer')
```

via: nyov on #scrapy irc